# separate seaborn scatterplot legend from plot for high dimensional legend

Tags: python, seaborn, legend, scatter, tsne

I have a seaborn python scatterplot with a legend that is too long to fit with the main plot.
Is there a way to save the legend separately. I know it can be done if I used [`matplotlib.axes.scatter` as in this gist](https://gist.github.com/rldotai/012dbb3294bb2599ff82e61e82356990) but I would like to use
seaborn as the representation is nicer.

```py
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(7)

plt.figure(figsize=(16,10))
fig = sns.scatterplot(
    x="tsne-2d-one", 
    y="tsne-2d-two",
    hue="labels",
    palette=sns.color_palette("hls", 3995),
    data=df_subset,
    legend='brief',
    alpha=0.3,
)
```

any help would be appreciated

[image: example image]

Comment: Have you tried implementing the code in the gist you linked? `sns.scatterplot` returns a `matplotlib.axes.Axes` so you should be able to access the legend in the same way.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I shall give that a try

Comment: You could try `ax = sns.scatterplot(...)` and then access the field `legend = ax.legend_`.